# Maven and Spring

Tags: maven-2

Hi  i am studying Spring In Action 2.0 and i am new to maven.
I am walking through the chapters and codes but i i got following error when i imported project through pom.xml on the pom editor in eclipse.

> 6/21/09 3:19:42 AM CDT: Missing
>   indirectly referenced artifact
>   incubator-activemq:activeio-core:jar:3.0-beta3:compile
>
> 6/21/09 3:19:42 AM CDT: Missing
>   indirectly referenced artifact
>   incubator-activemq:activemq-core:jar:4.0:compile

I downloaded the jar file and added to the library. still it does not work.
I am stuck what to do next? Can anyone help  me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add your pom.xml to the question

Comment: or add the results of mvn dependency:tree

Answer (score 2):

The referenced jars aren't available on the [Maven2 central repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven), so unless you have an additional repository declaration in your POM or an active profile in your settings, Maven will not know where to obtain the artifacts from.

There are a few public repositories like [here](https://test.kuali.org/maven/) and [here](http://repo.fusesource.com/maven2) hosting these artifacts.
To use these repositories you could add the relevant repository declaration to your POM or settings. See [here](http://www.dailydev.org/resources/maven) for an example configuration.

Alternatively if you don't trust the repositories you could manually download the jars and put them into your local Maven repository, though you'd need to be careful to replicate the structure Maven expects, and you may well encounter the same problem for different jars.

Another alternative is to use a Maven repository manager like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org/products.php), to manage Maven's interactions with external repositories, though that is almost certainly too much information if you're just starting out.

For general help/information on Maven, check out the [Maven book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/).

Comment: Yep, add a repository declaration for http://repo.fusesource.com/maven2 and it should work.